# Class newlfm letter does not have bottom margin for the second page

Tags: header-footer, luatex, fancyhdr, newlfm

I'm writing a letter with class `newlfm` and I have a somewhat big issue, the second page does not seem to have the bottom margin.

First page bottom:

[image: First Page]

Second page bottom:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{lipsum, xfrac}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}


\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=-100pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=0pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=0pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipafter=0pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=0pt}

\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

\namefrom{name Surname}

\dateset{May 6, 2019}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}

\closeline{Respectfully yours,}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance